# Keying an array with another?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array below:

```
    "checkbox_1": [
      "1"
    ],
    "checkbox_2": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_3": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_4": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_5": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_6": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_7": [
      "0"
    ],
    "checkbox_8": [
      "0"
    ]
```

I would like to know the best approach to have a paired array effectively storing a label as such:

```
$checkboxes = array('text value', 'text value, 'text value', '..');
```

if checkbox_1 is 1, then find the text value and output.

I've tried a foreach but feel there is some nice way of approaching this.

Comment: let's check `array_map` or `array_walk` functions.

Comment: You probably missed a single quote

Comment: It's better to have JavaScript submit the checkboxes as an array, i.e. `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

`array_intersect_keys` can help you. IMHO looks quite clean.

```
$c = [
    'a'=>1,
    'b'=>0,
    'c'=>1,
    'd'=>0,
    'e'=>0,
    'f'=>1
];

$d = [
    'asd1',
    'asd2',
    'asd3',
    'asd4',
    'asd5',
    'asd6'
];

print_r(array_intersect_key($d, array_filter(array_values($c))));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => asd1
    [2] => asd3
    [5] => asd6
)
```

http://ideone.com/YCBQvl